# Where is the source code for Polymer 1.0 Topeka App?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

- [Here is the Topeka app as it's found on Google App Engine Appspot](http://polymer-topeka.appspot.com/).
- [Here is the (purported) Github index.html file](https://github.com/Polymer/topeka/blob/master/index.html).

*Note: the app's source code is minified.*

## Question

> **Where is the un-minified source code for the Topeka app?**

1. If it's the [Github repository](https://github.com/Polymer/topeka/blob/master/index.html), then where (for example) is the file that's imported by `<link rel="import" href="components/topeka-elements/topeka-app.html">` and the others in in lines 46-51 of `index.html`? I don't see any `/contents/` directory in the repository.
2. If the source code is not the Github repository, where is it?
3. What's the deal with this minified `build.js` file, etc.? That's different from the customary `index.html` file. I haven't seen Polymer apps use that before.

---

#### Notes:

*@bpowers says on 9-14-2015 in [Polymer Slack Site](https://polymer.slack.com):*

it looks like they updated the build files a month ago, but its still old 0.5.  I was able to build it by opening up a terminal and doing:
`git clone https://github.com/Polymer/topeka && cd topeka && npm install && bower install && ./node_modules/vulcanize/bin/vulcanize -o build.html index.html --strip --inline --csp` -- clone it, move into the dir, install the deps, and then run vulcanize.  The vulcanize command is from the `deploy.sh` script in the repo.

if I run a web server in that directory, the build.html runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. That Github repo is the web application. The topeka elements are listed as a dependency in the `bower.json` - `"topeka-elements": "Polymer/topeka-elements#^0.5.0"`
2. [Find the source here](https://github.com/polymer/topeka-elements)
3. Looks like they've checked in the vulcanized build output from the deployment - see `deploy.sh`